# Shopify monitor that utilizes redis for caching each product

Tags: javascript

This is just a simple monitor for shopify products for an array of sites. It involves parsing the /products.json of the site, checking if each product ID is already stored as a key in redis and if it isn't it needs to notify a group of discord members (haven't implemented yet). Really appreciate any feedback given!

```
const axios = require('axios'),
      fs = require('fs'),
      redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient();

let trackingF = fs.readFileSync("../tracking.json");
let proxiesF = fs.readFileSync("../proxies.json");

let keywords = JSON.parse(trackingF).keywords.map(x => {
     return x.toLowerCase();
});

let sites = JSON.parse(trackingF).sites.map(x => {
    return x.toLowerCase();
});

let proxies = JSON.parse(proxiesF).proxies;

const getProducts = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(`${url}/products.json`, rProxy()).then(response => {
           resolve(response.data.products);
        }).catch(err => {reject(err)});
    });
 }

const cache = (product) => {
    client.get(product.id, (err, reply) => {
       if (err) console.log(err);
       if (!reply) {
           client.set(product.id, JSON.stringify(product));
           console.log("NEW PRODUCT: " + product.id);
           return;
       }
    });
}

const rProxy = () => {
    return proxies[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(proxies.length))];
}

const checkStock = () => {
    console.log("[MONITOR] CHECKING");
    for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
        getProducts(sites[i]).then(products => {
           products.forEach(product => {
               cache(product)
           });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}

setInterval(() => checkStock(), 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const axios = require('axios'),
      fs = require('fs'),
      redis = require('redis');
```

Personally, I discourage the use of a single `var`/`let`/`const` for declaring a variable. Firstly, they're not portable. Let's say you want to move `fs` somewhere else. Instead of copy-pasting the entire line, you end up copying that line *and tacking on* `var`/`let`/`const` anyways.

Next, say you already had `redis`. if you wanted to add `axios`, the Git changelog will look like:

```
- const redis = require('redis');
+ const axios = require('axios'),
+       redis = require('redis');
```

or this:

```
- const redis = require('redis');
+ const redis = require('redis'),
+       axios = require('axios');
```

Instead of just this:

```
+ const axios = require('axios');
  const redis = require('redis');
```

or this:

```
  const redis = require('redis');
+ const axios = require('axios');
```

You never touched redis, yet it's highlighted in the commit. This is because you had to add the `,`. This ends up being unnecessary noise in the commit, and annoying in code reviews and pull requests.

---

Next up, I recommend a `const`-first policy. The priority should be `const` first, then `let` if the variable has to mutate (e.g. loop counters). Then `var` if you absolutely have to have a function-scoped variable defined in some nested block for whatever reason.

This block-scoped variables reduce cognitive overhead, avoiding having to remember that what variables exist in the upper scopes, and to avoid accidentally clobbering a variable elsewhere. Small change in process, but has big benefits down the line.

---

Node.js has native support for `async`/`await`. So you no longer have to deal with the clunky syntax of promises.

Additionally, if you have functions that use the Node-style callback API (an async function that takes a callback whose first argument is an error and the second being the result), Node has [`utils.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) which returns a promise-based version of it.

---

```
for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    getProducts(sites[i]).then(products => {
       products.forEach(product => {
           cache(product)
       });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

You can replace this with an `array.map()` and `Promise.all()`. Put the promises returned by `getProducts()` in an array, pass that array to `Promise.all()` which returns a promise, await that promise to listen for the completion.

---

```
setInterval(() => checkStock(), 5000);
```

I'd wait for `checkStock()` to complete first before launching the next run. You wouldn't want to hammer the site every 5 seconds. They might not respond in time, and your requests may accumulate. You might be rate-limited or worse, blocked, before you know it.

---

Here's how I'd write it:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')
const redis = require('redis')

const trackingF = fs.readFileSync("../tracking.json")
const proxiesF = fs.readFileSync("../proxies.json")

const client = redis.createClient()
const clientGetAsync = utils.promisify(client.get)

const toLower = x => x.toLowerCase()

const keywords = JSON.parse(trackingF).keywords.map(toLower)
const sites = JSON.parse(trackingF).sites.map(toLower)
const proxies = JSON.parse(proxiesF).proxies;

const rProxy = () => proxies[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(proxies.length))]

const getProducts = async url => {
  const response = await axios.get(`${url}/products.json`, rProxy())
  return response.data.products
}

const cache = async product => {
  try {
    const reply = await clientGetAsync(product.id)
    if (reply) return
    client.set(product.id, JSON.stringify(product))
    console.log("NEW PRODUCT: " + product.id)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

const checkStock = async delay => {
  console.log("[MONITOR] CHECKING")

  const promises = sites.map(async site => {
    try {
      const products = await getProducts(site)
      await Promise.all(products.map(cache))
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  })

  await Promise.all(promises)

  setTimeout(() => checkStock(delay), delay)
}

checkStock(5000).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Comment: Really appreciate the advice, definitely time for me to go back over concurrency! Thank you.